# Servlet Mapping issue when called from two different folders

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml, servlet-mapping

File 1:  public_html/eval.jsp

File 2:  public_html/m/eval.jsp

File 1 form action:

```
action="submitEval"
```

File 2 form action:

```
 action="../submitEval
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>submitEval</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>submitPackage.submitEval</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>submitEval</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>submitEval</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Getting complaints of 404s when using the /m/ version of eval.jsp.  Not able to recreate but I figure if they are getting a 404 it would most likely have to do with my servlet mapping, any thoughts?

Comment: <url-pattern> should have a url and not just a string. putting "/" before "submitEval" in <url-pattern> should solve it.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz I have about 150 other servlets with a similar mapping (no leading "/") and none of them have an issue. I am wondering if the form action is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since i cant post it in the comment so i'm posting it as an answer.The only time i have seen or used  such mapping without any leading "/" is "*.anyString",and to test your mapping,i also went and tried the mapping which you are doing here,

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>coo.Demo</servlet-class>\
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>Demo</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

but i'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> Demo in servlet mapping`.But adding "/" or "*.Demo" fixes it as expected.
So i'm curious why is it working for you but not for me.